# .forEach() function doesn't recognise the element in the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Have this `.ejs` file which contains a `.forEach` a function which I am using to loop through an array. This array has only one element, and elements will be added in the future.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="bg-white jumbotron no-shadow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <%
                    if(apiResults.featured.male){
                        %>
                            <div class="row">
                                Array.from(apiResults.featured.male).forEach((profile) => {
                                    %>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <%=profile.name%>
                                        </div>
                                    %<
                                })
                            </div>
                        <%
                    }
                %>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Error:

```
profile is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:
618:12), <anonymous>:19:37)
    at returnedFn (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
    at include (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:651:39)
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:
618:12), <anonymous>:113:8)
    at returnedFn (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
    at include (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:651:39)
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:
618:12), <anonymous>:48:17)
    at returnedFn (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)

    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\projects\Heartenly\node_modules\e
js\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
```

Can anybody tell me why it doesn't recognise `profile`?

Comment: You seem to be missing `<%` in front of the `Array.from(…`, and also there's no proper `<% … %>` around the `})` of the loop

Comment: Any reason to use `.forEach()` instead of a simple `for … of`?

Comment: I think its a neater way of doing it